# Is there any way to determine a (multi) thread/task's stack address start in the virtual memory of a process on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, posix, virtual-memory

I know there potentially can be multiple different threading libraries that one use, but for this question I'm specifically thinking about POSIX pthreads.

Figuring out where the stack for the "process/main task/main thread/thread group leader" it's not all that difficult I think. Looking in the `/proc/` filesystem one can guess where this stuff is for a particular task.

What I want to be able to do, is find out where `pthread` placed the stack for the newly created thread and if this is even possible to figure out? This functionality would be, for instance used in a debugger like GDB.

One can pass stack address and stack size to the `pthread_create` function, so obviously some control over where it's located in virtual memory is possible.

Is there possibly a way to write a kernel module that looks at stack addresses of a `pid/tid` and determine from there, where in virtual memory of the process, where it's located? The `stack` member variable of `struct task_struct` in the kernel, seems to point to the physical memory and not the virtual memory, which is what I'm actually interested in.

ptrace doesn't seem to have an API for this either, which is unfortunate (for me). From a debugger's perspective this could be interesting information.

Looking at the stack pointer of a task and "going backwards" until a memory mapping's start, certainly isn't a clean way to do it and I'm not sure if that's even 100% certain to be correct either.

I would greatly appreciate if anybody had any ideas or if this is even possible.

Comment: You mean like https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getattr_np.3.html ?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you're trying to do.  You can find thread stacks by looking at the /proc/... info and look for the non-writeable stack pages - the thread stacks will appear immediately above the guard pages.  You could also call a function from the start of the thread function to look at the address of a stack variable, and estimate where the stack is located (IIRC there is an example implementation online)

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, it would be the equivalent of that, but remember (and I perhaps wasn't clear enough on that), the perspective is something like a debugger; the question relates to situations where "we" are not "the program", i.e. in a debugger situation we are the tracer and inspecting the tracee.

Comment: @Den-Jason I'm trying to figure out where pthread placed the individual stacks for threads, this can be used for many debugger-purposes, like checkpointing the application, using fork for instance and recreate threads, but you would have to know where their stacks were, not just their immediate context (like the register file of each individual task).

Perhaps the only way here would be to keep track of when threads are created in the tracee/debugee and look at new mappings that got mapped in during the creation of that thread.

Comment: See the sources https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/nptl/pthread_getattr_np.c#L81 . It reads /proc/self/maps and finds something inside __libc_stack_end

Comment: @KamilCuk thank you, that's a great lead, so maybe the proc fs is the way to go after all.

Answer (score 1):

> the question relates to situations where "we" are not "the program", i.e. in a debugger situation we are the tracer and inspecting the tracee.

You are probably looking for [td_thr_get_info()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/816-3324/6m9k4ve06/index.html) from `libthread_db`, which (among other info) returns

```
  paddr            ti_stkbase;        /* base of thread's stack area*/
  int              ti_stksize;        /* size in bytes of thread's allocated
                                         stack region*/
```

P.S. Looking in `/proc/$pid/maps` is a possibility, but you wouldn't necessarily know which anonymous mappings "belong" to thread stacks.